# Create LinkButtons with dynamic ID's

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've dabbled in the past with VB and ASP classic and am currently trying to write my first site in ASP.net and I'm very much learning as I go...but I've spent all of today trying to do this one and I've not got anywhere with the usual googling.

Hopefully it's apparent in my code that I am trying to dynamically add 2 LinkButtons with unique ID's below a LinkButton with a static ID.  I want the IDs in the 2 unique LinkButtons to have the "companyname" dataitem value in it so that I can unhide them when the first "companylink" is clicked - I'm yet to write the sub "LoadCompany" to unhide the two LinkButton's but I'm pretty confident I already know how to do that.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="leftsidebarcontent" runat="server">

    <li id="leftsidebarhead" class="sidebaritems">/* MENU */</li><br />
    <asp:Datalist id="customers" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <li class="leftsidebaritem sidebaritems"><asp:LinkButton id="CompanyLink" runat="server" OnCommand="LoadCompany" Text='<%#Container.DataItem("companyname")%>'></asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li class="leftsidebaritem sidebaritems"><asp:LinkButton id='<%#Container.DataItem("companyname")%> & "Reviews"' runat="server" Text="Reviews"></asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li class="leftsidebaritem sidebaritems"><asp:LinkButton id='LinkButton1' runat="server" Text="Other"></asp:LinkButton></li>
    <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Datalist>
```

If it helps - the first LinkButton is to populate a nav menu down the left of the page, below each one of these LinkButton's I want two further linkbuttons which will be hidden, until the original linkbutton is clicked, at which point they unhide - so creating a kind of nested navigation menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this in markup:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="leftsidebarcontent" runat="server">
    <p id="leftsidebarhead" class="sidebaritems">/* MENU */</p>
    <br />
    <asp:DataList ID="customers" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" OnItemCommand="customers_ItemCommand" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li class="leftsidebaritem sidebaritems">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="CompanyLink" runat="server"  CommandName="LoadCompany" 
                    Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "companyname")%>'></asp:LinkButton></li>
            <ul id="ulSubItems" runat="server" visible="false">
                <li class="leftsidebaritem sidebaritems">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID='LinkButton1' runat="server" Text="Reviews"></asp:LinkButton></li>
                <li class="leftsidebaritem sidebaritems">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID='LinkButton2' runat="server" Text="Other"></asp:LinkButton></li>
            </ul>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</asp:Content>
```

And in the codebehind:

```
 Protected Sub customers_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As DataListCommandEventArgs) Handles customers.ItemCommand
    'Hide all subitems
    For Each itm As DataListItem In customers.Items
        If itm.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse itm.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            Dim ulSubItems As HtmlGenericControl = CType(itm.FindControl("ulSubItems"), HtmlGenericControl)
            ulSubItems.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
    If e.CommandName = "LoadCompany" Then
        Dim MySubItems As HtmlGenericControl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ulSubItems"), HtmlGenericControl)
        If Not MySubItems Is Nothing Then
            MySubItems.Visible = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that afzalulh; looks like a nice solution.  I've actually found another way of solving the problem - but it's CONSIDERABLY less elegant (for each loop of dataset to generate nav table and subitems, using findcontrol to hide/unhide the subitems.  I'll be implementing yours next weekend; if only to learn a bit more.  Thanks again.